# How to view contents of an array while debugging in Code Blocks?

Tags: c++, arrays, debugging, codeblocks

This is probably a silly question and i am posting this Post-Googling, 
The question is,

> `How do i view the contents of an array while debugging, Provided the Breakpoint is in function not Main?`

I am using code::blocks 13.12 version and i set a break point in my sample simple c++ code,
and i want to observe how the contents of the array change with the code but **all i see is the the address of the array under watch window,**
It is however displaying the values of other integer variables correctly,

[image]

a is an array

I forgot to mention that i am tracking the array in a function and not in main,and i am aware that main passes the address of the array to the function being called(by reference i meant)

I am relatively new to codeblocks, Am i missing some setting or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am using 12.11. I select the array variable suppose a, choose "watch a" in the right button down menu, and I can see the values in the array a.

Comment: I am using 17.12, I right click to add vector a to watch and I can't see the values, just the same useless information as the original posted asked about.

Answer (score 7):

Right click on the cell, then select "Properties", there you can tell it to "watch as array", and tell it the index range to watch.

Comment: When I right click on the cell, all options including properties are greyed out except delete all option. Do you know why?

Comment: @zed111 It seems you cannot edit the properties of the automatic watches: function arguments and locals. You need to add that variable again to set its properties it seems.

Comment: That's right. Then, just go to the code and do what michaeltang said to add that variable again.

Comment: About telling the range:
Start must be 0 and
Count must be the array size

Answer (score 2):

Another thing that I use is watching under cursor.

If you go Settings -> Debugger... -> GDB/CDB debugger -> Default and you enable selection "Evaluate expressions under cursor", every time you leave mouse pointer above a variable in the code, it will be watched.

It's not the same with having it in Watches toolbar, but strangely it will show array's fields.

Answer (score 0):

Debug -> Debugging windows -> Watches

you may watch the variables in this way

in convenience, you can find button "Debugging Windows" near to the debug toolbar, choose "watch", hope you can find it!